# how to use Exist in List<string> in C#

Tags: c#

I have to find if string exist in a list to avoid duplicates inserts:
Here is example from Microsoft site:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();

        dinosaurs.Add("Compsognathus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Oviraptor");
        dinosaurs.Add("Velociraptor");
        dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Dilophosaurus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Gallimimus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Triceratops");

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach(string dinosaur in dinosaurs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dinosaur);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nTrueForAll(EndsWithSaurus): {0}",
            dinosaurs.TrueForAll(EndsWithSaurus));

        Console.WriteLine("\nFind(EndsWithSaurus): {0}", 
            dinosaurs.Find(EndsWithSaurus));

        Console.WriteLine("\nFindLast(EndsWithSaurus): {0}",
            dinosaurs.FindLast(EndsWithSaurus));

        Console.WriteLine("\nFindAll(EndsWithSaurus):");
        List<string> sublist = dinosaurs.FindAll(EndsWithSaurus);

        foreach(string dinosaur in sublist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dinosaur);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(
            "\n{0} elements removed by RemoveAll(EndsWithSaurus).", 
            dinosaurs.RemoveAll(EndsWithSaurus));

        Console.WriteLine("\nList now contains:");
        foreach(string dinosaur in dinosaurs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dinosaur);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nExists(EndsWithSaurus): {0}", 
            dinosaurs.Exists(EndsWithSaurus));
    }

    // Search predicate returns true if a string ends in "saurus".
    private static bool EndsWithSaurus(String s)
    {
        return s.ToLower().EndsWith("saurus");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to replace `EndsWithSaurus` function with lambda expression? 
Thanks everybody for your input!! Here is a working code:

```
        if (dinosaurs.Any(e => e.EndsWith("saurus")))
            Console.WriteLine("saurus exists");

        if (dinosaurs.Exists(e => e.EndsWith("saurus")))
            Console.WriteLine("saurus exists");
```

Comment: Two remarks for your replacement: 1) to compare, use `==` instead of `=`, which assigns; 2) when the method already returns true, you don't need to compare that value again.

Comment: If you **only** want to check for existence, a `HashSet<T>` may have value, note

Comment: You realize that your two solutions are functionally equivalent, right?

Comment: Yes, I did realize it. I only had a problem to decide which response should be mark as answer, yours or Sevenante. Sevenante has less points then you, that is why I decided in his favor. :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (dinosaurs.Exists(e => e.EndsWith("saurus")))
        Console.WriteLine("saurus exists");
```

The answer with `Any()` works fine too. The difference is just the `Exists()` method comes from `List<T>` itself and the `Any()` is just one of the great Linq extension methods (and will require `using System.Linq`)

Answer (score 17):

Use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx):

```
if (dinosaurs.Any(e => e.EndsWith("saurus")))
        Console.WriteLine("saurus exists");
```

You *could* use `List.Exists()` by just changing your lambda:

```
if (dinosaurs.Exists(e => e.EndsWith("saurus"))   // == true is implied
        Console.WriteLine("saurus exists");
```

but `Any` is more portable (i.e. can be used with *any* enumerable, not just `List`s.

Comment: Will need to add `using System.Linq`

Comment: @Sevenate Not a problem - yours works, too - I've been using `Any` for so long I forget that `List.Exists()` even exists.

Comment: @DStanley agree, it rare nowadays.