# ASP.NET MVC 5 session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to check if your session variable contains something... Just like a list has a method "Contains". Is there something similar to that? Some method or something?

Comment: Are you trying to see if Session itself contains something? Or if an object within Session contains something?

Comment: @mason if an object in the session contains something

Comment: You just need to cast it to the correct object type, then any methods that work on that object will be available.

Comment: @mason anyway I am getting an NullReference exception.. How can I check if my session object is null before converting it to string?

Comment: `myObject == null`

Comment: @mason When I use the Session["object"].ToString() I am getting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] not the actual object...

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) for `ToString()`? That is the expected behavior. Remember how I told you to cast the object to the correct type? Calling `.ToString()` is not casting. Try `List<string> myList = Session["object"] as List<string>`. Note that `myList` will be null if nothing existed in the Session with a key of "object". See the documentation for the [as operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx).

Comment: @mason I can't quite get you... I need the actual object inside it not the type of the object

Comment: I just explained how to get the actual object. Did you actually try the code I suggested?

Comment: @mason yes and I'm getting an compilation error

Comment: That's great. You know I'm not sitting at your computer to see what your error is, and that in order for me to be able to help you with it, you'd have to tell me what the error actually is?

Comment: @mason sorry I want debugging... Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: So whatever you have stored in `Session["object"]` is of type `string` instead of `List<string>`. Which were you expecting it to be?

Comment: @mason anyway that's not the actual problem... I am getting the type of the object not the actual object... Why doesn't .ToString() return the actual object converted to string?

Comment: @mason don't tell me that I have to override the .ToString() ...

Comment: Did you read the documentation I provided for `ToString()` above? That would answer your question. If you want the actual object, you need to cast to the type of the object you expect to receive. I assumed you were using `List<string>` because earlier you said `ToString()` resulted in in getting the text "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" but now you say you're getting an error message telling you it's a string. Sounds like you're storing different object types with the same key. A lot of this would be cleared up if you provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mason ok.. how do I convert the object inside the session Session["object"] so that it is now a string...

Comment: That depends on what type you stored in the Session. You have not explained what that is.

Comment: @mason it's a string

Comment: Really? Then why did calling ToString on it result in it saying it's a `System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.String]` (`List<string>`)?

Comment: @mason ops sry ... I meant list<string>

Comment: @mason so how do I convert it?

Comment: Just like I told you. `List<string> myList = Session["object"] as List<string>`

Comment: @mason you deserve a vote

Comment: more like a medal..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you retrieve items from `Session`, they are of type `System.Object`. This means that you don't get any of the actual methods available for the object's real type. You can do so by casting it to the correct type. In this case, it sounds like you're storing a `List<string>`. So we can use the [as operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx). If the object is not of that type or was null to begin with, `myList` will null. Otherwise it will be of the type you specify.

```
List<string> myList = Session["myKey"] as List<string>();

if(myList == null)
{
    //either Session["myKey"] was null or the object wasn't a List<string>
}
else
{
    if(myList.Contains("fuzzy puppies"))
    {
        //your list contains fuzzy puppies
    }
    else
    {
        //your list doesn't contain fuzzy puppies
    }
}
```

Calling `.ToString()` on an object gives you different results based on the object type. The default behavior is to print out the type of the object. But types can override this behavior. For example, calling `.ToString()` on a string just gives you the string itself. Calling `.ToString()` on an object that represents some XML might give you the XML as a string. Since `List<string>` doesn't override the default behavior of `System.Object.ToString()`, it just prints out "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

Comment: will be good to mention that .ToString() doesn't cast the object to string but just returns the object type

Comment: @john One step ahead of you, I've added an explanation already.

Comment: ...hehe nice one

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try casting your session so it can have a type for example

```
var listofperson = Session["ListofPerson"] as List<string>;

var hasGeorge = listofperson.Contains("George");
```

Answer (score -1):

First, check if Session["yoursession_var"] is null.  Then cast to List().  Then use Exists(), as described here: [how to use Exist in List<string> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108943/how-to-use-exist-in-liststring-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `.ToString()` does not cast to a string. And why would you use IndexOf instead [String.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Technically, you could use (string)Session["yoursession_var"], either one will get you a string that you can then use with either IndexOf() or Contains().   As for why I would not use Contains(), mathematical operations are usually more efficient than string operations, but if you look at the CLR, you will see that Contains() uses IndexOf() under the hood, so same diff.  Btw, I would try to avoid the magic strings -- constants are better.

Comment: 1) Contains is purpose built for detecting if a string contains another string, and doesn't require reimplementing code already in the BCL 2) ToString is not casting 3) The question is about List<string>, not string.

Comment: Agreed, my mistake about the cast, ToString() only works on primitives.  IndexOf() is my preference, I am a numbers guy :-)

Comment: ToString is still not the correct thing to use at all in this case, has nothing to do with being a primitive or not. And no, numbers having nothing to do with IndexOf. Contains is the code that is used to detect if a string contains another string. To use IndexOf for the same purpose is to re-invent the wheel and introduce needless complexity.

Comment: Agreed, my updated answer doesn't involve ToString().  The correct method to use is Exists(), which is why I updated my answer.  And to say that IndexOf(), which returns an int, which is a number, would refute "numbers having nothing to do with IndexOf."  Have a nice day :-)