# Keep asking for input if input is already known

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I have this code

```
public void givenLetter(){
        givenLetter = player1.giveLetter();
        if(guessedLetters.containsKey(givenLetter)) {
            return;
        }
}
```

**It needs to keep doing the `player1.giveLetter()` if the letter that returns is already known in the guessedLetters hash map.**

For example:

guessedLetters = {"A", "B"}

player1.giveLetter() returns "A"

run player1.giveLetter()

player1.giveLetter() returns "A" again

run player1.giveLetter()

player1.giveLetter() returns "C"

do rest of method

Comment: That's a nice problem statement, but you haven't actually asked a question.  What in particular are you stuck on?

Comment: @azurefrog It needs to run the function giveLetter() until it returns a letter that isn't known in the guessedLetters hash map.

Comment: Here's an example of what would work for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108943/how-to-use-exist-in-liststring-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to continue running the `giveLetter()` function until you're given an input that isn't found in the guessedLetters map.

To do this, I would suggest using a `while` loop.  A `while` loop will run until a given condition is `false`.

For example:

```
int i = 0;
while(i / 2 != 1) {
    i ++;
}
```

This loop will run while `i /2 != 1` is true.  Which would be true for i = 0 and i = 1, and false for i = 2 - so it would stop.

So given your problem, I would suggest:

```
public void givenLetter(){
    String givenLetter = player1.giveLetter(); // Get the letter
    while (guessedLetters.containsKey(givenLetter)) {  // While the given letter is found, continue to run the method.
        givenLetter = player1.giveLetter();
    }  // Exit the loop once the given letter is not found
    // Rest of function here
}
```

Comment: Isn't it now when the givenLetter exists in the hash map, it asks for a new one?

Comment: Yes, it would continue to ask for a new one until the given letter is not found the hashmap

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Something like this loop:

```
public void givenLetter(){
    while (true) {
        String givenLetterString = player1.giveLetter();
        if(!guessedLetters.containsKey(givenLetterString)) 
            return;
    }
}
```

It will run until the letter does not exist in the collection.

`while (true)` creates an infinite loop and it will only stop if the `return` statement is executed.