# Trying to .add to a list while already fill a list?

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I had this question posted with too little details and I deleted it to make it more clear here, its likely that isnt possible but I want to learn if it is, and didnt find anything about it online.
I got a class called (Student)
And in the controller a Listof(Student) and I am filling the data from SQL server
My code  is

```
    public class Student
    {
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public List<int> SubjectID { get; set; }
     }


//going back to the controller and what I am trying to do
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
Connection.open();
//the command doesnt matter but I am reading data from it that has ID Name Age and SubjectID
  while (reader.Read())
            {
                students.Add(new Student() 
                {
                     StudentId = reader.GetInt32(0),
                     
                     StudentName = reader.GetString(1),
                     
                     //Here I want to fill the StudentID list, I will start typing outside of the code space 
                                      
              });
            }
```

I hope the general idea is clear, I want (if possible?) to fill the StudentID list with what I get from SQL there, but since I already have the command ".add" there I cant use it inside it, also not sure if its possible to put an if statement, if the student is repeated start filling the student ID with one object inside the main list to look like this Students[0]={ Id= 1, name= Zaid, SubjectID= {1,2,3..}

I hope this made everything clear, again I know there is other ways to solve this without having to fill a list inside it but I want to know if its possible

Comment: https://thedeveloperblog.com/list-exists https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-check-if-an-item-exists-in-a-Chash-list-collection   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108943/how-to-use-exist-in-liststring-in-c-sharp

Comment: Just to be sure I am understanding what you are doing... the records you are reading are in the form `(ID, Name, Age, SubjectID)`? This means that you will have many records that refer to the same student, one for each subject the student is studying. Is that right?

Comment: @piadina Yes exactly that, for the example I put it will be first row => 1, Zaid, 1
2nd=> 1, Zaid, 2
3rd=> 1, Zaid, 3

Comment: Ok then, I will answer below in a moment

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thanks, I didnt know about that method but I dont think it will help in my case
Thanks Piadina tyt!

Comment: `if students.exists(reader.GetInt32(0))`  the get the list entry and add to its `.SubjectID` list, again prudent to check this list for what you are adding exists too.  You'll need to do some resarch/trying.  Give it a bit more than 20mins :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav There is no list entry, it's only one subjectID in each record, the student is repeated for each subject.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Well first of all, I did give it time and checking the links you gave none had a list of Objects, which contains multiple different types of values, if you read my example, I cant literally type if students.exists(reader.GetInt32(0)), because you are checking if a list of OBJECT has an INT, I might have a way around it without using the method exists, I will do a checker with bool and go with i (increasing each while loop is ended and if it exists do [i-1] and add the student ID in the previous part) 
But yeah I give it a thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to do that without changing your code too much.

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
Connection.open();
Student currentStudent = null;
while (reader.Read())
{
    // First, I read all the info
    int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
    string name = reader.GetString(1);
    int subject = reader.GetString(3); // I guess the subjectID is at this index based on your post
    // If it's the first record of this student, I create its instance
    if (currentStudent?.StudentId != id)
    {
        // I add the previous student to the list
        if (currentStudent != null)
        {
            students.Add(currentStudent);
        }
        currentStudent = new Student()
        {
            StudentId = id,

            StudentName = name,
            
            SubjectID = new List<int>() // I create an empty list for the subjects
        };
    }
    // I add the subject to the list for this student
    currentStudent.SubjectID.Add(subject);
}
```

This should give you the result you are expecting. It can be optimized and refactored, but it's something similar to what you already wrote. Let me know if it works correctly, I didn't run it.

Comment: THANK YOU! Now that works out and solves my question 100%.
Just curiosity since there is other ways I am getting into learning how to deal with database, <3 So really appreciate this help

If you can also help me figure out how to deal with the subject name if I want to add it 
It should be something related if the student ID is there I dont want the subject name to be overridden by the new value instead added it as a string (FirstSubject, Second, etc..) 
@piadina

Comment: There are many ways you could do that. I would add another class called Subject which contains two properties: `int ID` and `string Name`. Instead of having a `List<int>` for the subjects you will have `List<Subject>`. At this point you can create the Subject instance just before the last line in my code (reading the name and the id with the reader), and add it to the list.

Comment: Oh right! Thank you so much, nice ideas.
Appreciate your time, have a good day! :D

Comment: Have a nice day, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with SQL side, what, i think, much better, data must be deliver to you in the way u need, without any other stuff or minimal.

```
 SELECT st.StudentName, st.StudentId , STRING_AGG (sub.Id, ',') as 
 subjects

 FROM Student st JOIN 
 Subject sub on s.SubjectId = sub.Id

 GROUP BY S.Id, st.StudentName, st.StudentId
```

So, code must look like this

```
students.Add(new Student() 
{
    StudentId = reader.GetInt32(0),
                     
    StudentName = reader.GetString(1),
                      
    StudentId = reader.GetString(2).Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList()
                            
});
```

Comment: Thank you that seems like a good idea, again something new to me I am interested in. 
It looked good overall and it worked well but when I press the buttons in the form Ipasted the list in, I cant (for some odd reason) pass the list of subject Ids for that person, do you have any clue why that happens?

Comment: Any exception or you just don`t see result, provide more information, please

Comment: I have the values I passed written in a table (but the sub ID not written in the frontend)
Although there is buttons, one to edit one to delete, I used to pass StudentId with them but now I want to try and use the subject ID, so I write href="Controller/Function?SubID=@Stu.SubjectID" I expect it to pass a list of int to the function right? But it passes nothing
Or is that not possible

Comment: No, you can't transfer list just via link. As i understand, you want to see all the subject ids, so for that purpose you can create page, where you pass userId and find all it`s subjects

Comment: Okay thank you so much! 
On a different note have you ever used select2 in MVC view C# ?